# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (matches rows to an expression)

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization

I have this file:

[image: file]

And I wount to count the number of rows that have the expression "Hold centralized".

I have tried

```
      count(df.x="Hold centralized")
```

But i get this:

```
      syntax error:keyword can't be an expression
```

How can I count the number of rows that matches an expression?

Comment: `df.x.isin(["Hold centralized"]).value_counts()`

Comment: First thing, `=` is for _assignment_ not for checking for equality, which is `==`

Comment: Second, you seem to be mixing python and pandas. You should, if possible, stick to pandas or numpy methods for dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df[df["x"] == "Hold centralized"]["x"].count()
```